# .NET 6: Process.Start("powerpnt.exe") doesn't work anymore

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, .net-6.0

With Visual Basic .NET and .NET 6, `Process.Start("powerpnt.exe")` doesn't work anymore. What is the new way of calling up other apps now without having to call the entire path to the exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) object and set [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) to True:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo

With psi
    .FileName = "powerpnt.exe"
    .UseShellExecute = True
End With

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
```

With .NET 6, UseShellExecute is False by default (it was True by default in the .NET Framework).

Comment: Thank you! I assume this is the same for web pages? Like opening https://www.youtube.com ?

Comment: @FNDevCJ yes, same with URLs.